# How to set up OnClickListener to a group of imagebutton in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I knew how to set up OnClickListener to one image button.
But how do you set up a OnClickListener to one group of image buttons, such as 10 buttons.

Comment: put 10 ImageButtons into one ViewGroup, and then set up a OnClickListener to the ViewGroup...

Answer (score 0):

```
private val imageButtonClickListener = object : OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        v ?: return
        when (v.id) {
            // switch by id
            R.id.image_button1 -> {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a Collections addAll image buttons.
For example:

```
    val imageButtons = arrayOf<ImageButton>()
    imageButtons.forEach {
        it.setOnClickListener(imageButtonClickListener)
    }
```

Comment: Did your code use Kolin, not java?